# C# Hide base property in Attributes

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, attributes, validationattribute

I created a new attribute that inherits from ValidationAttributes, see code below:

```
public class BaseValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
        public string ShortNameKey { get; set;  }
        public string DescriptionKey { get; set; }
        public bool IsRequired { get; set; } = false;

        public BaseValidationAttribute(Type resource, string name)
        {
            ... initialization code ...
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            ... validation code ...
        }
}
```

There is a way to hide the ValidationAttribute public properties?
Specifically, my need is limited to hiding them while using the attribute.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to hide them?

Comment: If you don't want to use them, you can inherit from `Attribute` directly instead of `ValidationAttribute`

Comment: I have to hide them because we have some people working on this project. Exposing unused properties is misleading.


I have to replace the IsValid method. Attribute has no IsValid.